# Enum in a where query

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

```
class Conversation < ActiveRecord::Base
  enum status: [ :active, :archived ]
end
```

How would I construct a where query to fetch objects with the `status` attribute set to `:active`?

The following returns all:

```
Conversation.where(status: "active")
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should work:

```
Conversation.active
```

Comment: Why I asked for a `where` query was to make the statement chainable, but the answer you provided does exactly that aswell.